# Apple iOS Production Certificates - [ KeyChain Group ]

Tags: ios, certificate, keychain, provisioning-profile, production

The problem is the following ones:

we need to produce more than 2 apps with our developer apple account.

Currently, apple allows us to register another production certificate ( So the problem is not present now -- if we follow the same working flow in the apps' certification, but will occur in a pair of months when the 4th apps will be released).

I read aware that is possible to generate a kind of chain group, in order to reuse the same certificate among applications identifier. So it will allow us to generate for example:

- certificateA: generate 'com.company.appA'
- certificateB: generate 'com.company.appB'
- certificateG: generate [ 'com.company.appB.custom.A', 'com.company.appB.custom.B', ... ]

So how to do?

**[ EDIT ]**

**IMPORTANT REQUIREMENT**

All of these apps, use Push Notifications

Many thanks in advance

Comment: Why you need multiple certificates?No need to create multiple certificates for different Application. With single certificate you can distribute number of application.

Comment: Thanks for Answer A.H.Nuri. 
Even if i don't use wildcard ? 
Currently we use explicit identifier specificaitons. So how is possibile ?

Comment: Yes, Of course you can. With single certificate you can create or add multiple application.

Comment: Ok, but a problem persist to occur: 

 Check dependencies
     [exec] Code Signing Error: Provisioning profile "production-company-app-b-provisioning" has app ID "com.company.appB", which does not match the bundle ID "com.company.appB.custom.A".

     [exec] Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 12.1'

Can it depends for the matching prefix 

| com.company.appB |
| com.company.appB | .custom.A"  

?

Comment: Yes, .certSigningRequest or code signing certificate is required to verify your system and development account. 1. Create CRT from your system with KeyChain 2. Add CRT to your certificate (Developer account). 3. Add your Project to Identifier (bundle id). 4. Create your development and distribution provisional certificate under same certificate. Registered bundle Identifier( com.company.appb) with developer account and in Xcode should me same. Just try and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

**Distribution/Developer Certificate**

You can use the same Distribution/Developer certificate to sign multiple profiles.

**Provisioning profile**

Different for each apps. (if it is not wildcard)

You can use the same production certificate to sign multiple apps. Only provisioning profile will be different for each app.

You can create wildcard AppID and and provisioning profile and use it for multiple apps, but wildcard AppId's have some limitations like you cannot integrate push notifications for those apps which uses wild card profiles.

Comment: Thanks Prakash. 
You Got it! Push are my problems. So i'm not using wildcard. How to proceed ?

Comment: @SimoneCampagna you can create a separate provisioning profile for your app using same development/production certificate which you created for your other apps, there is no limit for creating provision profile and app id’s, only distribution certificates has limits.